# .htaccess authentication from a php script to prevent a browser dialog box

Tags: php, authentication, .htaccess, dialog

Using php I authenticate a user, then behind the scenes,they are then again authenticated a second time with a single .htaccess username & password. This would be the same for all users, but I would not want them to have to enter a username and password again and they would now be allowed to enter the password protected directory. I prefer not to use http://username@password:somedomain.com.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do this.

Either:

1. Add code to your .htaccess protected directory to use your PHP authentication scheme and remove the .htaccess authentication.
2. Write a new PHP page/script through which your authenticated users will access all of the protected content. Move the protected content out of the web root, or use your .htaccess file to deny all access. Your script will be able to access the files, but users will have to go through the script to access them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid multiple logins but need HTTP authentication, you can use *only* HTTP authentication for the actual login. This is because PHP can issue and respond to such headers.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

This way the user receives a pop up, PHP can read it and respond accordingly and the browser will pass it with subsequent requests eliminating further prompts.

Note: This solution is not available to CGI versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not believe this is possible (unless you want to use the username:pass@url scheme). You could write some ajax to do it behind the scenes, which would mean that the browser will remember the auth for that area (maybe, I have never actually tried it). But you would still need the username/pass regardless.

For the security of not transmitting the password in clear text on the browser (I assume you are using https to transmit the password over the network, or if your not you should!) I think it will be a little annoying for the user, but not a huge amount of hassle in my opinion.

Of course you could do the authenticating on that other folder in PHP, which would solve the issue, or put all your protected code in the one place with the one HTTP auth, but I assume you dont want (or cant) do this.