# PHP: Use PHP to authenticate with .htaccess when uploading to a subfolder of the protected folder

Tags: php, authentication, .htaccess

I'm trying to upload files to the subfolder of a protected folder. Here is what the hierarchy looks like:

> /basefolder(.htaccess)/tool/script.php
>
> /basefolder(.htaccess)/tool/uploadhandler.php
>
> /basefolder(.htaccess)/tool/files/here(subfolder)/

The simple .htaccess file for my basefolder is:

```
AuthUserFile "/path/"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Admin Dashboard"
require valid-user
```

The script sends data to the typical php upload handler which attempts to save the file in the subfolder. When the code gets to this stage my browser prompts me for the user/pass again.

Is there a way to authenticate using PHP so that I don't get prompted for the password every time?

Comment: Possible dupe of [#2694697](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694697/htaccess-authentication-from-a-php-script-to-prevent-a-browser-dialog-box)

Comment: If your upload handler saves the file directly in the tool folder, do you still get prompted a second time? Have to checked to make sure you don't have another .htaccess file in the tool folder, the files folder, or the subfolder?

Comment: Also, using Basic Authentication is not typically recommended, since passwords are sent in clear text, unless you're using SSL. Anyone on the same Wi-Fi network could read the password.

Comment: I still get prompted when saving directly in the tool folder. There are no other .htaccess files in any of the subfolders under basefolder. I thought the upload handler wouldn't need authentication since it uses the server side user and that user should have full access to all folders on the server?

Comment: Please paste the code for your upload handler into your question. It almost sounds as if you are trying to save the file via HTTP rather than using PHP to save it directly to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Exempt the `upload.php` file from HTTP password protection and use sessions or a cookie to set that the user is allowed to upload.

For example, in the PHP file with the upload form:

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['can_upload'] = true;
// this would only be set if the user could successfully access the upload form
// page; sessions are preferable to cookies since anyone could set a cookie named
// "is_allowed" to "1"—you would have to use some kind of token for validation
// if you used a cookie
```

and then in the PHP file handling file uploads,

```
session_start();

if (! isset($_SESSION['can_upload'])) {
  header("403 Forbidden");
  echo("You are not authorized!");
  die();
}

// user is OK, put your upload logic here
```

Comment: No good. I found that the problem was to do with my flash uploader and that I had to disable mod_security for it to work. So I abandoned it for a jquery uploader.